# How do you unlock the mini games in mario party?

Tags: mario-party

I have the very first mario party on n64 that I recently just purchased. I forgot how you're supposed to unlock the mini ganes that appear as ???? when you go to purchase them in one of the buildings. Could anyone help?

Comment: I think you just have to play them first in whatever the main game mode is, but it's been so long I can't say for certain.

Comment: See, that's what I originally thought myself but I hadn't seen any appear while playing in the normal party mode. So that's what confused me. It has also been a super long time for me which is why I have completely forgotten.

Answer (score 3):

You must play them in the main game before they can be purchased in the [Mini-Game House](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Party#Mini-Game_House) . When the Mini-Game roulette wheel stops on "?????", the name will be revealed and will be available once the game (not Mini-Game) is finished.